# How do I make the "user operation is waiting" dialog invisible in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm creating a web development framework with Eclipse RCP.

The wizard is creating a feature that creates a project when you press Finish.

I want to show Process Monitor at the bottom of the wizard

I wrote the code as below.

```java
public abstract class CreateProjectWizard extends Wizard {
    
    public CreateProjectWizard () {
                
        ...
        
        setNeedsProgressMonitor(true);
    }
    
    ...
    
    @Override
    public boolean performFinish() {
    
        IRunnableWithProgress runnable= new IRunnableWithProgress() {
            
            @Override
            public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
                    ...
                    
                 IStatus status = createProject(input, monitor);

                    ...
            }
        };
        
        try {
            getContainer().run(true, true, runnable);
        }   
        
        ...
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

How do I make the "user operation is waiting" dialog invisible?

I will let you know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be able to call `Dialog.setBlockedHandler` with something that implements `IDialogBlockedHandler` to change this dialog (both in `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs`).

The blocked handler does not have to display a dialog, the default JFace handler is just:

```java
new IDialogBlockedHandler() {

        @Override
        public void clearBlocked() {
            // No default behavior
        }

        @Override
        public void showBlocked(IProgressMonitor blocking,
                IStatus blockingStatus, String blockedName) {
            // No default behavior
        }

        @Override
        public void showBlocked(Shell parentShell, IProgressMonitor blocking,
                IStatus blockingStatus, String blockedName) {
            // No default behavior
        }
    };
```

Eclipse normally replaces this with `org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchDialogBlockedHandler` which shows the dialog you see (`BlockedJobsDialog`).

Note that this will not stop the operation waiting for the blocking jobs to finish it will just stop the dialog appearing.

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply, I have an additional question.